# Demonstrating iOS in-development application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I'm developing iOS application for my customer. At final point he asked me to **share "preview" of an app via link** before he could pay me for it. How do I do that?

1. How do I show my iOS app to someone, is there any other way aside from uploading it to AppStore and therefore making it public and needing developer account (I don't have at the moment)?
2. If I upload an app to AppStore, is it possible for my customer to "steal" and save it (through installing to jailbroken device for example and copying app with file manager), I suppose this is how users of jailbroken devices download and install paid apps for free using torrents?
3. What is the common practice of doing this, I mean demonstrating app in development to customer? On my own device? Bringing laptop with Xcode installed and using customer's device?

Comment: get a developer account and send a testflight build

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programming

Comment: where do I ask this question then?

Comment: Send him a development build of the app. You can use test flight or something like this I find is good https://www.diawi.com

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Thanks @ThePumpingLama for a link, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 - How do I show my iOS app to someone, is there any other way aside from uploading it to AppStore and therefore making it public and needing developer account (I don't have at the moment)?**

The recommended method is to use testflight or Diawi if you can get an account from client?
If not, then you are limited to very few options, either arrange a physical meeting and demonstrate the app to the client, or make a video call and share the screen with the client while on call.

**2 - If I upload an app to AppStore, is it possible for my customer to "steal" and save it (through installing to jailbroken device for example and copying app with file manager), I suppose this is how users of jailbroken devices download and install paid apps for free using torrents?**

Though i didn't get what you are asking here, but let me make things clear on what i understand. Customer won't be able to steal the app, it will be downloaded from the AppStore using TestFlight. And what's he going to do with the app ? you have the source code, so i guess don't worry on this.

**3 - What is the common practice of doing this, I mean demonstrating app in development to customer? On my own device? Bringing laptop with Xcode installed and using customer's device?**

As already mentioned in point 1, you can not install the application to any non jailbroken device untill you have the Apple development account. Once you have it you can create the ipa file and distribute it using any distribution services, like Apple's own Testflight or Diawi.

Comment: testfairy is another good option

Comment: Haven't used it but seems like a better option.
Thanks

Comment: Do I have to know client's device UDID to use diawi or test fairy of testflight?

Comment: Yes you will have to create a development provisioning profile. The profile will have all the device UDIDs you want to test.